# web application custom url dev?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, url

I'm in the stage of planning a web application and I'm wanting to allow the user to create a custom url to their profile page, I've seen something that I like on soundcloud where a user clicks the title and a textbox appears the user can then change the url to his/her liking (am assuming some jquery validation goes on at this point).

Haven't been able to find anything online regarding this (unless its specifically called something). So can someone point me in the right direction or tell me is the url management dealt with via the database or the .htaccess?

completely stumped but it looks wicked so thanks ahead if you can help.

Comment: I'd imagine this kind of stuff is handled by the application itself.

Comment: it's just like a `clean url` for seo. If i would do this, my approach would be wrapped the handler in the .htaccess then save the custom url in the database.

Comment: You know the type of pattern you'd want to allow as a unique profile, so create a `.htaccess` to point to a `profile` page matching that pattern, and in the `profile` page, match the input you `get` to a DB row that will match the user to show their profile.

Comment: If you're using a framework like Codeigniter, you could have a url like www.domain.com/user/custom_url_part where custom_url_part would be a variable that's passed to the user controller which then does something clever with it.

Comment: could I set it up so that it was www.domain.com/custom_url_part or is that outside the remit of codeigniter?

Comment: You could do it that way with CodeIgniter, but you'd need to do some custom routing work - CI's default routing is set so that the first param after the domain is the controller, and the second is the method to be called.

Comment: @user1888564 You could do that if all requests to `http://www.domain.com/nonexistantfolder` is redirected a processing page that parses `nonexistantfolder` to decide what user profile it should target.

Comment: ok so essentially if a file was inside a folder happily called process.php then the custom url could pull the data from the database using the string as a key and return the result?

Comment: Also would I be able to use backbone.js if I use a framework such as cake or codeigniter - spent a while learning it and hate to give that up.

Comment: I seriously recommend you use `Meteor` to make your program (http://meteor.com) - also for backbone and such you can use `page.js`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's not a way to do it, i would use some framework, but if i put a framework name here it would generate some discussion, so, that's **`my`** logic:

```
WebServer > Check file existence RewriteCond on Apache, try_files on Nginx
 '-- File exists > ignore
 '-- File doesn't exist then pass the request to a Router file
      '-- Check > Check if it's a system request, like '/register'
         '-- Match > Process the request itself
         '-- Doesn't Match > Validate for a possible username
              '-- Is a valid username
                   '-- Look for that user on database
                   '    '-- User exists > internally redirect for profile process
                   '    '-- User doesn't exists > 404
                   '-- Is not a valid user > 404
```

Also:

> I recommend CakePHP

Comment: I hadn't factored in a framework for this but feel I may need to do some research as to whether a framework could offer a stable and scaleable solution to my app.

Comment: so you recommend I go baking?

Comment: If you need something really fast, you should use CodeIgniter, if you need something fast and is starting on framework's world, i recommend CakePHP, but there's `n` others frameworks, like Zend, Yii, Symphony and more.

Comment: does codeigniter create html5 output for forms etc?

Comment: I think only CakePHP and Yii will bring that to you. But CodeIgniter have some workarounds.

Comment: thanks - i plan to use backbone.js to handle the requests to the server - if I use a framework such as you have recommended will it not be the case?

Comment: http://www.slideshare.net/RichardMcIntyre/using-backbone-with-cakephp, i searched on google and i found it

Comment: thanks just thought i'd ask as i was typing on here ;-)